# Automated Network Mapping

Tags: networking, mapping

What tools do you suggest I use to create a network map? I prefer to do it automatically rather than go around and collect information per computer. I know spiceworks does something along those lines, do you have anything else to suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solarwinds makes a pretty good product called [LANsurveyor](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/lansurveyor/)

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [The Dude from Mikrotik](http://www.mikrotik.com/thedude.php)

Answer (score 1):

nmap with the zenmap GUI has some mapping functionality.